# Quantum wave function evolution and time dilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, time-dilation, dirac-equation

We know that spin state evolves with time...but in non relativistic QM time dilation is not accounted ...so in Dirac equation does evolution of spin state with time depend on speed...i.e does time dilation effect individual quantum particles..any mathematical proof would be also appreciated

Comment: the Dirac and  Klein Gordon and the quantized Maxwell which are used to calculate interaction in the relativistic regime incorporate Lorenz invariance afaik, there is no reason to bother with time dilation as it is in a different frame of reference, not the one involving the particles in the interaction.

Comment: For a dramatic illustration of time dilation on wave function evolution see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/muon.html#c3.